# Access property of class that is the property of another class?

Tags: c++, class, object

I am trying out my hand at C++ and wanted to access the name property of the `Job` class from the `Player` class. The codes for the .h and .cpp files are below.

**Foo.h**

```c++
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <vector>  
  
class Job {  
    public:  
        char* name = "";  

    Job() = default;  

    Job (char* name) {  
        name = name;  
    }  
};  
  
class Player {  
    public:  
        char* name = "";  
        char* id = "";  
        char* job_name = "";  
        Job job;  
  
        Player() = default;  
  
        Player(char* name, char* job_name) : name(name), job_name(job_name), job(job_name) {};  
};
```

**Foo.cpp**

```c++
#include <iostream>  
#include "Foo.h"  

int main() {
    Player player1("player1", "default");  
    std::cout << player1.job.name;  
}
```

However, I received the error below.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE5436F551 (ucrtbased.dll) in Foo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

I suspect the error is due to me calling player1.job.name as calling player1.name on std::cout works fine, but am unsure why this is not allowed / illegal. If so, what is the correct way to call player1.job.name? Should I use getters to access the properties for Job() class instead? In that case, would I need getters for every single property? How should I structure my getters to call nested properties? Why is player1.job.name not allowed?

If not, is the error due to something else instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `char*` for strings, this is C++ so use std::string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Why do you think `name = name;` does?

Comment: `char*` is just a pointer. When you copy the pointer you are not copying the string it points to (though it would "work" here as you are only using string literals)

Comment: If you must:  `strcpy()`, `strcat()`, `strcmp()`, `strchr()`, and `strdup()`.  The `std::string` is a lot simpler and less error prone.

Comment: And `player1.job.name` is very much allowed, but only if all the pointers are properly initialized.

Comment: @Evg I was under the impression name=name assigns the variable given when instantiating the class to the name property in the class. e.g Job job1("default') would result in name="default" but it seems I would be mistaken. 

Thank you everyone for the help, I learnt a few things and have noted on using std::strings instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code lies in how you initialize the name member of the `Job` class. Let's go through the corrections step by step.

In your `Job` class, you should use `const char*` instead of `char*` for string literals, and you need to properly initialize the name member in the constructor. Also, it's a good practice to use `std::string` for managing strings.

```
class Job {
public:
std::string name;
    
Job() = default;
    
Job(const char* jobName) : name(jobName) {}
};
```

Similarly, in the `Player` class, it's better to use `std::string` for managing strings.

```
class Player {
public:
std::string name;
std::string id;
std::string job_name;
Job job;

Player() = default;

Player(const std::string& playerName, const std::string& jobName) 
: name(playerName), job_name(jobName), job(jobName) {}
};
```

In your main function, you can then access `player1.job.name` without any issues.

```
int main() {
Player player1("player1", "default");
std::cout << player1.job.name << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

By making these changes, you are ensuring that the string data is properly managed, and you won't run into issues with accessing invalid memory locations. Using `std::string` eliminates the need to manually manage memory for strings.

If you still want to use character arrays (C-strings), you need to make sure that you allocate memory for them properly and manage it throughout the program, but using `std::string` is generally more convenient and safer in modern C++ code.

Comment: `Job(const char* jobName)` should be `Job(const string& jobName)`.

Comment: out of curiosity, did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?